# How to Undo the Moving effect

Tags: apache-flex

I have a very simple problem. I want a component move right when a mouse hover it, and the component will be move back when the mouse is at elsewhere. and the code I come up with is like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               xmlns:ns1="*"
               minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <fx:Style source="testproject.css"/>

    <fx:Declarations>



        <s:Move3D id="nueffect" target="{menuC}"  xBy="+100" />
    </fx:Declarations>

    <ns1:menu id="menuC" x="-296" y="155" mouseOver="nueffect.play();">
    </ns1:menu>

</s:Application>
```

My question is how do I implement the effect when the mouse is not hovering the component?

Comment: mouseOut="nueffect.end()" seem not working. =.='

Comment: I think I had solved it.

Comment: mouseOut="nueffect2.play();"  and nueffect2 is the reverse action xBy="-100" is this the only way?